# How to configure Yum to update from self-hosted repository

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, repository

I have a Red Hat instance (which I'll call "A") that I would like to use as a repository for updates rather than the redhat-subscription-manager.

I also have another Red Hat instance ("B") that I would like to point to "A" to get updates from.

The tutorials I've followed thus far have gotten me to the point that I've created a repo on "A", but I can't figure any further than that, along with how to update the packages in said repo.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The "right" way is Red Hat Satellite.

Comment: `The tutorials I've followed thus far have gotten me to the point that I've created a repo on "A"`. Please add the config and the path to the file you have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## create repo file

From [RHEL Deployment Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Setting_repository_Options.html):

> The following is a bare-minimum example of the form a [repository] section takes:

```
[repository]
name=repository_name
baseurl=repository_url
```

So pick a name for your repo and replace `repository_name` with that.  Hopefully you've configured a web server like [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) or [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) to serve your repo.  Replace `repository_url` with the URL for your web server hosting the repo.  (Feel free to test this URL with curl or your web browser first.)

If you want your repo to be enabled by default add `enabled=1` to the repo file.

### put it in `/etc/yum.repos.d`

Reference: [RHEL Deployment Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Managing_Yum_Repositories.html)

Placing your file into `/etc/yum.repos.d` and making sure the file extension is `.repo` will get it read by yum.

Red Hat also provides:

> Yum repositories commonly provide their own `.repo` file. To add such a repository to your system and enable it, run the following command as root:

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo repository_url
```

> …where `repository_url` is a link to the `.repo` file.

But when you're just starting out and testing using `scp` to get the file there is ok.